# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int : [String]]' with an index of type 'String!'

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

please, ask me, where is my mistake? I have Xcode error:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int : [String]]' with an index of
>   type 'String!'

in let keyExists = myDict[tmp.Hour] != nil, myDict[tmp.Hour] = Int and myDict[tmp.Hour].append(tmp.Minutes) of that part of code:

```
func array() -> Dictionary <Int,[String]>
    {

        let timeInfos = getTimeForEachBusStop()

        var myDict: Dictionary = [Int:[String]]()


        for tmp in timeInfos {

        let keyExists = myDict[tmp.Hour] != nil
           if (!keyExists) {
                myDict[tmp.Hour] = [Int]()
            }
           myDict[tmp.Hour].append(tmp.Minutes)
            }
        return myDict
    }
```

I understand, that problem is in optional type, but where is problem I don't understand

upd

```
 func getTimeForEachBusStop() -> NSMutableArray {

        sharedInstance.database!.open()
        let lineId = getIdRoute

        let position = getSelectedBusStop.row + 1


        let getTimeBusStop: FMResultSet! = sharedInstance.database!.executeQuery("SELECT one.hour, one.minute FROM shedule AS one JOIN routetobusstop AS two ON one.busStop_id = (SELECT two.busStop_id WHERE two.line_id = ? AND two.position = ?) AND one.day = 1 AND one.line_id = ? ORDER BY one.position ASC ", withArgumentsInArray: [lineId, position, lineId])


        let getBusStopInfo : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

        while getTimeBusStop.next() {

            let stopInfo: TimeInfo = TimeInfo()
            stopInfo.Hour = getTimeBusStop.stringForColumnIndex(0)
            stopInfo.Minutes = getTimeBusStop.stringForColumnIndex(1)
            getBusStopInfo.addObject(stopInfo)

        }
       sharedInstance.database!.close()
       return getBusStopInfo

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `getTimeForEachBusStop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that you cannot subscribe your `[Int:[String]]` dictionary with a `String` key.

Therefore the type of `tmp.Hour` is obviously `String` rather than the expected `Int`

If `tmp.Hour` is guaranteed to be an integer string you can convert the value

```
let hour = Int(tmp.Hour)!
myDict[hour] = [Int]()
```

On the other hand since `myDict` is `[Int:[String]]` you might mean

```
let hour = Int(tmp.Hour)!
myDict[hour] = [String]()
```

Comment: thanks, but in future I need Int type of dictionary's key, how better convert type of key from String to Int?

Comment: thank you and I found my new error with your help. Now everything is working OK! Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your dictionary as a dictionary with keys of type `Int` and values of type `[String]`:

```
var myDict: Dictionary = [Int:[String]]()
```

(better written as: `var myDict: [Int: [String]] = [:]` because by casting it to `Dictionary` you are removing the types).

However, in

```
myDict[tmp.Hour] = [Int]()
```

You are using a value which is of `[Int]` type and `tmp.Hour` is probably a `String`.

So, your problem is a type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Hour and Minutes are of type `string` (I guess - `stringForColumnIndex`) so your dictionary is wrong type. Should be:

```
func array() -> Dictionary <String,[String]>
{

    let timeInfos = getTimeForEachBusStop()

    var myDict: Dictionary = [String:[String]]()


    for tmp in timeInfos {

    let keyExists = myDict[tmp.Hour] != nil
       if (!keyExists) {
            myDict[tmp.Hour] = [String]()
        }
       myDict[tmp.Hour].append(tmp.Minutes)
        }
    return myDict
}
```